# Xamarin Android emulator not working in VS2015 Professional

Tags: c#, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, android-emulator

I have used Xamarin for Android in VS 2015 Professional and I was always able to debug my code using the emulator Android_accelerated_x86 (Android 6.0 - API 23). But from yesterday when I click debug, the emulator takes ages to start and once started it is very slow and the app I am trying to debug doesn't even start. 
Since I did nothing to change settings in Visual Studio, I am really confused and not sure how to fix this and make it work again. Any suggestion? Any detail I could share to show the problem?

In the output window of VS the output seem to stuck to:

1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml

1>  Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\styles.xml

Comment: I've problem with Emulator and Debug. I prefer to use the phisical device. When in debug mode it cannot always work. In release mode i don't have problem. For example, i don't get to receive push notification when i'm debuging, but when i'm in release ,mode work fine, no problem. Try out in release mode and see if working.

Comment: Stop the deploy, clear your `obj/bin` folders and re-deploy

Comment: Yes release is working cause no emulator is involved there.

Comment: Cleaning the solution didn't help

Comment: This will be a good solution instead of VS android Emulator https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player/  after install use ADB CONNECT {EMULATOR IP} to connect